Access a member field of a derived class from a pointer of the parent type
Let's say I have two classes, A and B:
class A { };

class B : public A
{
private:
    int Bvalue{};
}

And I have a pointer of the class A that is a member field of class C:
class C
{
private:
    A* ptr{};
};

If the pointer points to an object of class B, how could I access the Bvalue without using dynamic_cast every time I want to access to this element ? Dynamic casting would be slow if the operation is done a lot of time. Is there maybe a way to convert the type of the ptr member field ?
I tried doing a virtual function that would return Bvalue in class A, but obviously class A doesn't have access to the Bvalue so it doesn't work. I could make it return 0, and then I would also put the function in classB, but that's not optimal. Here what it would look like:
class A
{
public:
    virtual int getBvalue() { return 0; };
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    int getBvalue( return Bvalue; );

private:
    int Bvalue{};
}


Just use static_cast instead.

In class C, have an additional B* ptr_b{} member variable that is set by doing the dynamic_cast just once, when the ptr is set.

Why can't C hold a pointer to B?

static_cast would be better than dynamic_cast but if I used it a lot it would have some cost right ? For the additional pointer in class C, I'll need a lot of them if I had a lot of derived class, so I don't think it would be the best idea, but I'm not sure.

You would be casting pointers. The only way to have less overhead is to store a pointer to 'B' instead. See also

@TripotinD.Muel There is essentially no cost to static_cast for pointers (If you don't have other base classes in B before A, they normally have the same address so the static_cast does nothing at runtime. If the address is different, it's only adding a constant value to the pointer, which will be combined with anything you add to access members)

Okay I see, thanks a lot! I'll use static_cast.

First of all there are a lot of errors in your code. Ignoring it if you declare the function as virtual and pointer points to B object you should get the value of the Bvalue. Since only the pointer is of A type but its pointing to B object and that has Bvalue. Some of the typos like ';' after function declaration inside class, inheritance syntax  : public A  (not class A).

Here's an idea: don't use inheritance. Problem solved.

This whole thing seems like a design problem. If you're using A*, you should generally only perform operations that apply to A, not operations that depend on it pointing to a specific subclass.

I think that your idea to use virtual function is good.
Especially taking into account that in your initial example Bvalue is a private member of B class.
If the problem is in "what should virtual method in parent class return then?"
You can solve it by returning into a reference:
class A
{
public:
    virtual void getBvalue(int& out_val) { };
};

class B : public A
{
public:
    void getBvalue(int& out_val) override {out_val = Bvalue};

private:
    int Bvalue{};
}

It is not ideal, but fits the task.
Personally, I would still consider returning by value and if I do not want to "allocate" specific value of the field for "empty state" (as 0 in your example).
I would try to return std::optional from the getter.
Then your parent virtual method can return std::nullopt.
Or you can return pointer to the value and the parent method will return nullptr.

Assuming that sometimes class C will hold a pointer to an A object and sometimes it will hold a pointer to a B object, one option is for class C to store the actual type of the pointer then do a static_cast as appropriate which is basically free from a performance stand point.
To make dealing with this type of code easier, c++17 introduced std::variant which simplifies dealing with code that does not know the exact type of an object at compile time.
